# NSRegularExpression for hashtags and mentions with special characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, hashtag, nsregularexpression

I'm using the following regex expression to detect hashtags and mentions in my app.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#|@)(\\w+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

However users within my app are allowed to use some special characters in their usernames. For example `@user.name` or `@user_name`. Spaces are not allowed. However using thins regular expression would only detect `@user` when it should in fact be `@user.name`. Hostages work perfectly but the special characters in usernames break the mention functionality.

I'm really new to regex and I'm not sure what I need to change to fix this. I'm pretty sure its something to do `\\w+` but what exactly I could do with some help.

Comment: Do you only need to support  a period or anything else? Try `@"[#@]\\S+"` to allow any non-whitespace, or `@"[#@]\\S+\\b"` to make sure the last character is a word character.

Comment: @"[#@]\\S+\\b" works perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to match any non-whitespace characters after `@` or `#` but the last character of this sequence must be a word character, you can safely use

```
@"[#@]\\S+\\b"
```

Note that an alternative group `(#|@)` works more effeciently when transformed into a character class `[#@]` (it involves less backtracking).

[Regex breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/dT4mK6/1):

- `[#@]` - match a `#` or `@`, 1 time
- `\S+\b` - match 1 or more non-whitespace characters but the last one must be at the word boundary.

A bit more enhanced version (to make sure the first character after `#`/`@` is a word character and the whole username is at least 1 character long):

```
@"[#@]\\w\\S*\\b"
```

Note that this [second version](https://regex101.com/r/dT4mK6/2) will not support such names as `@-nick.name-`.