# Separate keywords and @ mentions from dataset

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a huge set of data which has several columns and about 10k rows in more than 100 csv files, for now I am concerned about only one column with message format and from them I want to extract two parameters. I searched extensively around and I found two solutions that seem close but are not enough close to solve the question here. [ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735272/nsregularexpression-for-hashtags-and-mentions-with-special-characters) & [TWO](https://regex101.com/r/dT4mK6/1#python)

Input : Col name `"Text"` and every message is a separate row in a csv.

```
"Let's Bounce!ðŸ˜‰  #[message_1]

 Loving the energy &amp; Microphonic Mayhem whileâ€¦" #[message_2]

RT @IVijayboi: #[message_3]   @Bdutt@sardesairajdeep@rahulkanwal@abhisarsharma@ppbajpayi@Abpnewd@Ndtv@Aajtak#Jihadimedia@Ibn7 happy #PresstitutesDay

 "RT @RakeshKhatri23: MY LIFE #[message_4]

        WITHOUT YOU 

        IS

        LIKE 

        FLOWERS WITHOUT 

        FRAGRANCE ðŸ’žðŸ’ž

        ~True Love~"


  Me &amp; my baby ðŸ¶â¤ï¸ðŸ‘­ @ Home Sweet Home  #[message_5]
```

The input is a CSV file with several other columns in the data but I am interested only in this column. I want to separate the `@name` and `#keyword`from the input into a new column like:

expected output

```
text, mentions, keywords 
[message], NAN, NAN
[message], NAN, NAN
[message], @IVijayboi, #Jihadimedia  
           @Bdutt      #PresstitutesDay
           @sardesairajdeep 
           @rahulkanwal 
           @abhisarsharma 
           @ppbajpayi 
           @Abpnewd 
           @Ndtv 
           @Aajtak  
           @Ibn7
```

As we see in the input first and second message has no `@` and `#` so the column values `NAN` but for the third message it has 10 `@` and 2 `#` keywords.

In simple words how do I separate the @ mentioned names and # keywords from the message to a separate column.

Comment: Can you add your current code as well? Your input and output data is quite cryptic, so I don't quite get what you want to do here.

Comment: I am in position where I am not understanding how to read whole message as row and from that how to separate.  So the situation is like other than import packages I am not able to write any code :-(

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to use a regular expression. I don't know the exact format that your @ mentions and # keywords are allowed to take, but I would guess that something of the form `@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]` would work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

test_string = """Text
"Let's Bounce!ðŸ˜‰
Loving the energy &amp; Microphonic Mayhem whileâ€¦"
RT @IVijayboi: etc etc"""

mention_match = re.compile('@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
for match in mention_match.finditer(test_string):
    print(match.group(1))

hashtag_match = re.compile('#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
for match in hashtag_match.finditer(test_string):
    print(match.group(1))
```

Hopefully that gives you enough to get started with.

Comment: Thank you so much. For Starters I can begin with this.